# How to create a store and get store id in mail chimp for drupal commerce?

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I need store id(store_id) to pass the value in this API.
/ecommerce/stores/{store_id}/carts

Answer (score 0):

You need to first add a store to MailChimp using below API. Whatever id you pass in this request will be your store id for the subsequent requests.

https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/ecommerce/stores:

```
    {
      "id" : "store_001",
      "list_id" : "205d96e6b4",
      "name" : "Freddie's Jokes",
      "domain" : "www.freddiesjokes.com",
      "email_address" : "merchandise@freddiesjokes.com",
      "currency_code" : "USD"
    }
```

You can further check the Api at:
https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/ecommerce/stores/